# Create a pod from a failing k8s CronJob

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a CronJob which runs every 10 minutes and executes some command.

It's failing for some reason and I want to `exec` into it to investigate and fix it (There's a 1 time command I need to run to fix a shared volume*).

The issue is when I try to run `exec` I get this error, which is expected:

```
error: cannot exec into a container in a completed pod; current phase is Failed
```

I would like to create a new pod from the job definition and run a custom command on that (e.g. `tail -f`) so that it runs without crashing and I can `exec` into it to investigate and fix the issue.

I've been struggling to do this and have only found 2 solutions which both seem a bit hacky (I've used both and they do work, but since I'm still developing the feature I've had to reset a few times)

1. I change the command on the k8s YAML file to `tail -f` then update the Helm repo and `exec` on the new container. Fix the issue and revert back.
2. Copy the job to a new `Pod` YAML file in a directory outside of the Helm repo, with `tail -f`. Create it with the `kubectl apply -f` command. Then I can `exec` on it, do what I need and delete the pod.

The issue with the first is that I change the Helm repo. The second requires some duplication and adaptation of code, but it's not too bad.

What I would like is a `kubectl` command I can run to do this. Kind of like how you can create a job from a CronJob:

```
kubectl create job --from=cronjob/myjob myjob-manual
```

If I could do this to create a pod, or to create a job with a command which never finishes (like `tail -f`) it would solve my problem.

*The command I need to run is to pass in some TOTP credentials as a 1 time task to login to a service. The cookies to stay logged in will then exist on the shared volume so I won't have to do this again. I don't want to pass in the TOTP master key as a secret and add logic to interpret it either. So the most simple solution is to set up this service and once in a while I `exec` into the pod and login using the TOTP value again.

One more note. This is for a personal project and a tool I use for my own use. It's not a critical service I am offering to someone else so I don't mind if something goes wrong once in a while and I need to intervene.

Comment: can you post the cronjob yaml? generally it should have the job spec and the job spec should have the pod spec which you can use..

Comment: @DanielM, yeah that' what I'm doing at the moment (see option 2 from the question) it works but I was hoping there would be some kind of built in command I'm missing to do this without having to extract the pod spec.

Comment: Another option to troubleshoot it could be adding a sidecar container where you can exec into and check what was going on inside the pod. As for suggested solution, I don't think there's a one command for it. There's no suitable options for [kubectl create](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#create) as well as [kubectl run](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#run).

Answer (score 1):

Looked into this question more, your **option 2 is the most viable solution**.

Adding a sidecar container - it's the same as option 1, but even more difficult/time consuming.

As mentioned in comments, there are no options for direct imperative pod creation from `job`/`cronjob`. Available options can be checked for `kubectl`:

- [`kubectl create`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#create)
- [`kubectl run`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#run)

Also tried out of the interest (logic is to run the command from `cronjob` and then continue with specified command), but did not work out:

```
$ kubectl create job --from=cronjob/test-cronjob manual-job -- tail -f
error: cannot specify --from and command
```